# How to close content by clicking anywhere but excluding the content itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I can't make the content to stay open, when I click on itself. It closes when I click on the button that triggers it and when it's clicked anywhere (which is right). I'm targeting the document,  because I'm going to  have different functionalities, based on different tag elements.

How can I prevent the content from closing when clicking on the content itself?

[image]

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g9vvjLw/)

**Javascript**

```
$( document ).on( "click", function( event ) {

// Add internal reference
$( ".target-2" ).addClass( "gStarter" );
$( ".content-col" ).addClass( "gColumn" );


// Check if the elem been clicked has target-2 as class
// and if the tag name matches a button tag
if( $(event.target).hasClass( "target-2" ) && $( event.target ).prop( 'tagName' ) == "BUTTON" ){

    // Add active class if it doesn't have it
        if( ! $( ".target-2" ).parent().next().children().hasClass( "active" ) ){

            // Make sure there won't be any content activated
                    //$( ".gColumn" ).removeClass( "active" );
        //$( ".gStarter" ).removeAttr( "data-starter" );
        // Add active class
        $( ".target-2" ).parent().next().children().addClass( "active" );     
  } else {
      /*
       * Already have active class
       */

      // Hide content by removing the class
      $( ".target-2" ).parent().next().children().removeClass( "active" );
      // Remove data-starter attribute
      $( ".target-2" ).removeAttr( "data-starter" );
    }

} else {

  // Find and get the first class by targeting its data-starter attribute
  //var find = $('[data-starter="starter-active"]');
 // var getClass = $(find).attr('class').toString().split(' ')[0];


  if ( ! $( ".target-2" ).closest().parent().next().children().is( event.target )) {

    if ( $( ".target-2" ).parent().next().children().is(':visible')) {

      $( ".target-2" ).parent().next().children().removeClass( "active" );
    }
  }     

}

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="host">
 <div class="btn-container">
   <button type="button" data-starter="starter-active" class="target-2 target">Click here</button>
 </div>
 <div class="button-row row">
   <div class="button-col content-col">
     <span>This content is triggered by a button - ID: 13</span>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you confirm - is your intent to disable the hiding of the containing blue div element when a user (1) clicks anywhere within it or (2) clicks on the text itself?

Comment: The content shouldn't close when clicking anywhere in the content, but it should close when clicking anywhere outside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `closest('.contentClassName')`  and *return* if target is in that content class

```
$( document ).on( "click", function( event ) {

    if($(event.target).closest('.button-row').length){
       return; /// don't go any further
    }
    // other code is same
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1g9vvjLw/9/)**</kbd>

Comment: Just noticed that it will only work before all the code and I don't want to build more if statements to check what tag names are they. Would be better if it is integrated where it should be.

Comment: No idea what "where it should be" means

Comment: I believe it should be on the main last "else" statement.

Comment: Not sure why that would make sense. One thing to consider is perhaps breaking your code up into functions if it is going to get more elaborate. As for answering your original question what I provided does exactly what was asked

Comment: Because as I explained, that different element name tags will work in a different way. I cannot use a global class as it will interfere with other codes. And this is just an example / portion of a plugin.

Comment: what does that have to do with answering the original question? If you have more complications should ask another question not try to evolve a whole section of your app in comments. The principal I gave you is the same regardless of where you use it.

Comment: You're right! Nvm, I apologize for the inconvenience. I was really overthinking it. I just noticed that it should work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check if the target has a specific class name?

For example, add a class name to

```
<div class="button-row row my-content" />
```

And then check if the $(event.target).hasClass('my-content').

Besides, you could make it dynamically by using **data** attributes.

Add a data attribute on the **Click Here** button. Like this:

```
<div data-content-target="my-content">Click Here</div>
```

Then, in the javascript, instead of walking the DOM tree (parent().next().children().addClass()) just select the Element and add the active class as following:

```
var targetContent = $(".target-2").data("content-target");
$("." + targetContent).addClass("active");
```

This is a better approach, for many reasons, but first of all, it reduces the complexity of your code a lot.

Comment: definitely, I will consider it!